# Dynamically align divs side by side

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic, alignment

I'm working on parent-children relationship. I have a company model and product model, when I pull the record of the products of a company I want them to be aligned side by side, since divs by default aligns vertically, how do I make them align horizontally? I have seen a couple of answers that shows how to do this statically but since these are dynamic records, how do I align them side by side using divs generated dynamically?

```
@foreach($product as $products)
  @if($company->id === $products->company_id)
     <div class="flow">{!! Html::linkRoute('companyContactView', $products->productname, $products->company_id) !!}</div>  |  
  @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Tried `float : left;`

Comment: I've tried it, it didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: If you have tried something which does not work, better you put it in your question so that others will try correct your code.. _didn't work_ is not that expressive..

Comment: Sorry, that's the reason I added the class, This is its content: `.flow{
  float: left;
  width:auto;
  clear:left;
 }`

Comment: Thanks. I got it working. Thank you for your support. I just removed the bold tag. I don't know why it should be the problem.

Comment: You would have saved few minutes if you would have posted your code earlier.. Anyways, Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

The preferred way to allow multiple divs to be side by side is to apply the CSS rule `display: inline-block`. This allows you to specify a width and height.

Check out this example from w3schools:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp

I encourage you to use the 'Try it yourself' example to see how inline-block works and why it it is preferred over using float.

Comment: The only thing I'd add to this is that you need to specify width and height in px, not %.

Answer (score 1):

This CSS rule might help, assuming `flow` is the parent.

```
.flow {
  white-space: nowrap;      /* make them stay on 1 line all the time */ 
}

.flow > div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;      /* or middle, or ..., how you want them to align */
}
```